# How to link post to topic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I made a latest posts box in my app at the root. In this box I have post which belongs to topic. Maybe its a stupid question but how can I redirect click on post to the topic where it belongs?

This redirects me to localhost:3000/topics, how to add topic_id's to this path?

This is how I get the latest posts:

controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
    # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
    helper_method :latest_posts
def latest_posts
      @posts ||= Post.all.order("created_at desc").limit(3)
end
end
```

index:

```
<% latest_posts.each do |posts| %>
  <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-warning">
    <p><%= link_to post.content.html_safe, topic_path(post.topic) %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :users
  get 'categories' => 'categories#index'
  resources :topics
  resources :posts
  resources :users
```

Routes:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
              categories GET    /categories(.:format)          categories#index
                  topics GET    /topics(.:format)              topics#index
                         POST   /topics(.:format)              topics#create
               new_topic GET    /topics/new(.:format)          topics#new
              edit_topic GET    /topics/:id/edit(.:format)     topics#edit
                   topic GET    /topics/:id(.:format)          topics#show
                         PATCH  /topics/:id(.:format)          topics#update
                         PUT    /topics/:id(.:format)          topics#update
                         DELETE /topics/:id(.:format)          topics#destroy
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)               posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)               posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
                    root GET    /                              categories#index
```

Comment: `topic_path(post.topic)`? Can you post your routes to give us a little clarity.

Comment: I already tried that way  @Justin but I got error: `undefined local variable or method `post'` I updated routes.

Comment: You must not be iterating through the `posts`. Please refer to [this Rails Guides post](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#using-partials-to-simplify-views).

Comment: I added an answer to reflect the changes mentioned in the comment above. It should get you to your solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to first iterate through the `posts`, then link to the `topic` base on the single instance of `post`.

```
<h5>Here are all of my posts</h5>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= link_to post.content.html_safe, topic_path(post.topic) %>
<% end %>
```

Here is a solid [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html) post on ActionView and rendering. It's definitely worth the read.

Comment: I still get `undefined local variable or method `post'` What should I do in controller? I already trying to solve this from 3 hours and nothing... I updated a question, you can see how I get the latest posts.

Comment: change `<% latest_posts.each do |posts| %>` to `<% latest_posts.each do |post| %>`

Comment: Yep. When you iterate through an array, the variable you use as your *block parameter* is the variable allowed in the block. ie: if the block parameter is `post`, when the variables `posts` will be nil inside the block and vise versa. That's where your undefined method came from.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have defined the `show` route in your `config/routes.rb`, you can use the `topic_path` helper.

```
<%= link_to posts.content.html_safe, topic_path(topic) %>
```

Where `topic` is the instance which you want to redirect to.